# Trying to print to test a program to see it print a name and the contents of that name only if it is included in the file that it is reading

Tags: java

This is a java program that works with a class file that I did not list here. My problem is:

It prints the list from the file just fine, but  I need to now make the program ask the user for a last name. The program then has to check from the file to see

- if that last name was included and
- if it was to then print out the information profile of that last name such as the first name and the quiz average. Also
- if it is not a last name used in the program to then state no last name found

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;//you need this to read the Employee file
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class QuizAverages8 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String sFindStu ="";
    ArrayList<Student> StudentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    generateEmpList(StudentList);
    System.out.println("STUDENT ROSTER AND QUIZ AVERAGES");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Students in class: " + StudentList.size());
    System.out.println("");


    for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < StudentList.size(); nIndex++){
        printEmployee(StudentList.get(nIndex));
    }
```

// This is where I want to test to check the program if the last name is used

```
    System.out.print("Please enter the last name of a specific student: " );
    sFindStu = input.next();
    if (sFindStu.equals(StudentList.contains(args))){
       System.out.println(StudentList.get(nIndex));
    }   
    else{
        System.out.println("No name with " + sFindStu + "Found");
    }
```

// It ends here

```
}        
public static void printEmployee(Student myStudent){

System.out.println("Employee Name: " + myStudent.getFirstName() + " " + myStudent.getLastName().toUpperCase());
System.out.println("Quiz average: " + myStudent.calculateQuizAverage());
System.out.println(" ");
}



public static void generateEmpList(ArrayList<Student> list) throws 
FileNotFoundException{
    String sFileName = "Students.txt";
    String sInputLine = " ";
    File fileToOpen = new File(sFileName);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileToOpen);
    String[] saTokens = null;
    ArrayList<Student> empList = new ArrayList<Student>();


    while(inputFile.hasNext()){
        sInputLine = inputFile.nextLine();
        saTokens = sInputLine.split("-");
        Student emp = new Student();//create empty object
        emp.setFirstName(saTokens[0]);
        emp.setLastName(saTokens[1]);
        emp.setQuiz1(Integer.parseInt(saTokens[2]));
        emp.setQuiz2(Integer.parseInt(saTokens[3]));
        emp.setQuiz3(Integer.parseInt(saTokens[4]));



        list.add(emp);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please spend the time required to learn how to properly format your input for us. There is no point in use // comments for ... pure text. Seriously: you want us to spend our time to help you with your problem, so you please spend the time required to come up with *easy to read* input.

Comment: It is easy to read. I labeled the only part of the code I need help with. The rest is basic stuff I already have working.

Comment: I just told you that I find your input to be *not* easy to read. And you then conclude "but it is easy to read". Yeah sure. Because I am telling you that for no reason at all.

Comment: So, I took the freedom to make your question actually readable ... and honestly: your whole question boils down to "somebody help me finishing my homework". Because you aren't asking for a single thing, you are asking for quite a bit of functionality here.

Comment: That is almost identical to what I wrote! I know how to do this for a function that is not an array. I am a game designer afterall, so coding is something I am used to doing when I dictate what I need. It just so happens that when using an array I cannot figure out how to ask for an individuals name to check because this is not something I normally use ever.

Comment: Well, I took the time to **re format** your messy input, trying to make it **easier to read**. That is the whole point. And make no mistake: your source code is as *hard to read* as your question. Seriously: focus on *one* thought, and follow that one. You are constantly throwing several things together - and then you expect others to read your mind and to somehow conclude what you possibly did hide in that pile of stuff you left behind.

Answer (score 1):

So, boils down to:

```
if (sFindStu.equals(StudentList.contains(args))){
```

being wrong on so many levels. You see, the point of being a "coder" is about *understanding* the abstractions you are using. How do you understand them? By reading their *documentation*. By using a search engine that leads you to tutorials others have written.

Meaning: `ArrayList` is a Java `Collection`, and yes, therefore it provides a `contains()` method. As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) suggests:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element.

But of course, Lists are **generic**, so when you have a `List<String>` then you can only pass a **single string** to it, like:

```
if (someStringList.contains(someString))
```

The compiler won't let you pass an **array**, because you declared a List of String. You can't ask a list of eggs whether it contains a sampler of eggs.

So, as written: instead of asking the list if contains an array of strings (which by the way: the **args** you are passing there has **nothing** to do with your other code, does it!), ask the list if it contains, like the player name:

```
if (StudentList.contains(sFindStu)) {
```

Done.

And of course: the real answer is that you should change the way you approach problems. You seem to pull together concepts without spending much time *understanding* them. That is a pretty inefficient strategy. You have to understand **each and any** character that you write down in your source code. Instead of throwing together things of which you *assume* they maybe luckily do what you need them to do.

Beyond: read about Java naming conventions.